# How do I set up one page that containers the <header></header> and can be linked to all pages?

Tags: html, css

I want to create one page to contain the `<header></header>` for all my pages. Meaning I can link all my stylesheets without having to go page by page.

Any ideas? I'm using Visual Studios.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, IE=11">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="author" content="Drool Design Studio">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Drool Design Studios">

    <title>Drool Design Studio</title>

    <!--FAVICON-->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/logo/favicon.png" />

    <!--STYLE SHEETS-->
    <link href="style/global.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="style/header.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="style/sections.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="style/footer.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="style/buttons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="style/scroll.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="style/reviews.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!--JS-->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/662c8a0fc8.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

Comment: Do you have some kind of server/templating system?

Comment: There is no way to do this in pure html. You can use templating languages that generate your html though

Comment: I don't I'm afraid. Could you recommend a template language I could adapt my website to?

Comment: Easiest one to Learn is IMO is Jekyll. You can find information here https://jekyllrb.com you should be able to easily copy everything over. It’s one of the more simple template engines. It's also advised to load your JS scripts at the bottom of your page, just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you use PHP for this. Make a file 'header.php' and include that in every other PHP page with: `include 'header.php';`

But PHP works on the server, so you need to have a server space somewhere to run it on. You can test a server at home on your own computer with Apache though: https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html